# TemplateDoesNotExist at / Home.html Exception Type: TemplateDoesNotExist

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

1. My Customers urls.py

'''
from django import urls
from django.urls import path
from django.urls.resolvers import URLPattern
from . import views

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.Home ,name= 'Home'),
    path('Hall/', views.Hall ,name= 'Hall'),
    path('Food_item/', views.Food_item ,name= 'food'),
    path('About_us/', views.About_us ,name= 'about'), 
]
'''
```

2. My Web_project urls.py

   ```
             '''

        from django.contrib import admin
        from django.urls import path, include

       urlpatterns = [
      path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
      path('', include('customer.urls')),
     ]

             '''
   ```
3. Settings.py Templates

   ```
     '''  


    TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
   ```

   ]
4. Customers View.py

   ```
      '''
   ```

   from django.http.response import JsonResponse
   from django.shortcuts import render

   ```
    def Home(request):
        return render(request, "Home.html", {"title":" Home"})

    def Hall(request):
        return render(request, "Hall.html", {"title": "Hall"})

    def Food_item(request):
        return render(request, "Food_item.html", {"title": "Food_item"})

    def About_us(request):
        return render(request, "About_us.html", {"title": "About_us"})

        '''
   ```
5. My cd is web_project>customer>templates>customer>Home.html
6. The error it showing

   ```
    '''

    Template-loader postmortem
    Django tried loading these templates, in this order:

    Using engine django:

     django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader: C:\Users\Nawaf 
     Bhatti\Desktop\New\web_project\templates\Home.html (Source does not exist)
     django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: C:\Users\Nawaf 
     Bhatti\Desktop\New\env\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\templates\Home.html 
     (Source does not exist)
    django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: C:\Users\Nawaf 
    Bhatti\Desktop\New\env\lib\site- 
    packages\django\contrib\admin\templates\Home.html (Source does not exist)
    django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: C:\Users\Nawaf 
    Bhatti\Desktop\New\env\lib\site- 
    packages\django\contrib\auth\templates\Home.html 
   (Source does not exist)
    django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: C:\Users\Nawaf 
    Bhatti\Desktop\New\web_project\customer\templates\Home.html
   (Source does not exist)

    '''
   ```

Comment: return render(request, "customer/Home.html", {"title":" Home"}). try this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding the path from the `templates/` subfolder like so:

```py
def Home(request):
    return render(request, "customer/Home.html", {"title":" Home"})
```

Comment: Now it is showing this  'TemplateSyntaxError at /
Could not parse the remainder: '/css/bootstrap.min.css' from 'customer/css/bootstrap.min.css'

Comment: That's a different issue. This means you probably didn't setup your static folder and put your static files at the right location.

Comment: This is how i give paths                                                                       
 <img src="{% static customer/img/footer-logo.png %}" alt="">